# Elastic Beanstalk won't recognize absolute path to file, returns FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Flask application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The application deploys successfully, but there is a task in my code where I use pandas `read_csv` to pull data out of a csv file. The code line is:
`form1 = pd.read_csv('/opt/python/current/app/application/model/static2/form1.csv')`
When I try to execute that task in the application, I receive a FileNotFoundError:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/opt/python/current/app/application/model/static2/form1.csv' does not exist: b'/opt/python/current/app/application/model/static2/form1.csv'`

The problem does not occur when I execute the program locally, but only if I use the full, absolute path to the file. This is due to the way my dependencies are set up.

When I first deployed the application, I received errors because I was still using the local path to the file, and so I changed it to the one you see above, which is what I *think* is the absolute path to the file uploaded on Beanstalk. I think this because I copied it from a static image that I was having an issue with earlier.

I should note that I cannot verify the absolute path because I am unable to remote into Elastic Beanstalk using EB CLI. I have been trying to get EB CLI set up on my machine for days and repeatedly failed, I think because of weird version and file issues on my machine. So I can't obtain information or fix the problem using command line.

So, is the path that I am using above consistent with an EB absolute path? Can this be solved by adding to my static file configurations? If so, how?Is there anything I could add to the .config file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! My process was being carried out by rq workers. The rq workers are running from my local machine and I did not realize that it would be the workers looking for the file path. I figured this out by printing `os.getcwd()` and noticing that the current working directory was still my local path. So, I threw an exception on a FileNotFoundError for the workers to use a local path instead as necessary.