# Directory path of root folder after deployment in Elastic Beanstalk - Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, directory, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, filepath

I have a folder in the root of my web app zip file that I need to be consistently accessing after deployment on Elastic Beanstalk. How would I do this in my application.py file?

I have tried:

- My full file path for my Mac that works on a local server
- Just the folder name
- '/opt/python/current/app/' + folder_name

The third one seems to give me health problems to the point where I need to rebuild my environment because it keeps timing out. I am trying to access a simple Machine Learning model that I have saved in this folder, so the line of code in application.py is something like `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(folder_path)`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use relative path, instead of absolute one? Also is it Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: @Marcin Would relative path be easier? Also I am using Amazon Linux 1

Comment: Yes, because they would be valid regardless where your parent folder is. Can you try with relative paths?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838423/elastic-beanstalk-wont-recognize-absolute-path-to-file-returns-filenotfounderr

Comment: @HunterSwag Did you find any solution to this? Please let me know if fixed, I am facing the same issue.